# Accessing array value

Tags: php, oop, pear, quickform

print_r($fanr);

results in:

```
HTML_QuickForm_text Object
(
    [_label] => FA-Nummer
    [_type] => text
    [_flagFrozen] => 
    [_persistantFreeze] => 1
    [_attributes] => Array
        (
            [name] => auftragsnr
            [type] => text
            [value] => 123
        )

    [_tabOffset] => 0
    [_tab] =>   
    [_lineEnd] => 

    [_comment] => 
)
```

trying to output the value of name with

```
echo $fanr["_attributes"]["value"];
```

Did not work.
The error.log tells me

```
[Tue Oct 27 13:58:08 2009] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type HTML_QuickForm_text as array in C:\\htdocs\\apps\\u-antrag\\upload_form.php on line 97
```

Please, tell me where I made the mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your variable `$fanr` is an object, not an array. you have to use `$fanr->_attributes['value']` to access its members.

alternatively you can implement the [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/arrayaccess) interface

Answer (score 2):

`$fanr` is an object not an array. As such, use the `->` operator to access members.

```
echo $fanr->_attributes['value'];
```

Comment: Thank you - the error.log shows it clearly. Time to visit my optician.